# Creating directory in internal storage android

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to create directory in directory. To create one directory simply call this:

```
File dir1 = getDir("dir1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

But how to create other directory in `dir1` ?

this:

```
File dir2 =getDir("dir1"+"/"+"dir2",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

throw exception:

```
File dirFile = java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File app_dir1/dir2 contains a path separator
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Context.getDir() appears to be an Android-unique method for abstracting out the process of creating a directory within the private storage area - it is not a generic way of making directories in general.

To make your child subdirectory, you should use normal java methods, such as

```
File dir2 =new File(dir1, "dir2").mkdir();
```

Note that the first parameter here is the File Object representing the first directory you created, not the name.

You may want to subsequently set the permissions on this directory.

*warning: untested*

Comment: @Marky changing this to the mkdirs() method is not needed - because the parent directory is known to exist, mkdir() is sufficient.